# Is there a function that allows for verbose assertions?

Tags: python

Frequently when I am writing code I add assertions for my own sanity, specifically for when I am first writing the code to ensure I do not implement it with bugs (I understand assertions are ignored in production builds of code). Whenever I write an assertion, I find myself verbosely writing something along the lines of:

```
assert a == b, f"{a} != {b}"
```

So that if my assertion fails, I have some way of interpreting *why*. Unfortunately, this often clutters my code, as if the variable names are long (or I am in nested structurees), adding the message at the end often makes the line too long to be consistent with [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length). So I spend the time breaking it up over several lines, which also makes a basic assert a multi-lined statement.

`unittest` provides helpful [assert methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#assert-methods) like `assertEqual` which shorten this work, make it less prone  to me leaving out the error message, and allows me to continue on with my work rather than worrying about assertions. The only two options I can come up with are:

1. Write my own function to be verbose. This would require re-writing many of the assert functions; or
2. Instantiate an instance of `unittest.TestCase()` each time I want to make an assertion.

The problem with number 2 is it is unbelievably slow:

```
>>> min(timeit.repeat('unittest.TestCase().assertEqual(a, b)', setup='import unittest; a = 1; b = 1'))
1.7452130000000352
>>> min(timeit.repeat('assert a == b, f"{a} != {b}"', setup='a = 1; b = 1'))
0.01641979999999421
```

Which is a hint that this would be bad practice ie. `unittest` should be used for unit testing, not generic assertions.

I'll admit this question is a bit nit-picky, but StackOverflow often has the ability the enlighten me on libraries/ideas that make programming faster, safer, and better, so I'd like to know: is there a better (built-in?) method for verbose assertions, or should I simply continue writing them verbosely as I have before?

Comment: Even if you disable assertions, does their presence throughout the code make it easier to read and maintain? In other words, is this even a problem you need to solve, or would it be better to focus on proving the correctness of your functions with external tests? Tests are not necessarily written afterwards: they can be written before.

Comment: There is no such function in stdlib. In test code, use pytest which will give a verbose assertion context by default.  If you have assertions firing from _library_ code frequently, you're using asserts wrong in the first place - they should never fire unless something is seriously amiss. Do not use assertions for input data validation, use them only to validate statements which you as a programmer are sure are tautological.

Comment: @wim so how does pytest do it?  Would love to import whatever function they use.  Test is failing but output is truncated, so in debugger I want to run assert on some pieces of expected and result containers.

Comment: @JakeStevens-Haas Pytest does it with [assertion rewriting](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/assert.html#assertion-introspection-details). That requires pre-processing of the test code, so it would not be practical to do this interactively in a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adapt some code from `unittest` to create some functions which do not require to instantiate a full-blown TestCase, here is a small example :

```py
import difflib
import pprint
from unittest.util import safe_repr, _common_shorten_repr


class Asserter:  # this class consists mostly of code from `unittest.TestCase`

    def assertEqual(self, first, second, msg=None):
        assertion_func = self._getAssertEqualityFunc(first, second)
        assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)

    def _getAssertEqualityFunc(self, first, second):
        if type(first) is type(second):
            asserter = {
                dict: self.assertDictEqual,
                # ...
            }.get(type(first))
            if asserter is not None:
                return asserter
        return self._baseAssertEqual

    def _baseAssertEqual(self, first, second, msg=None):
        """The default assertEqual implementation, not type specific."""
        if not first == second:
            standardMsg = '%s != %s' % _common_shorten_repr(first, second)
            raise AssertionError('%s : %s' % (standardMsg, msg))

    def assertDictEqual(self, d1, d2, msg=None):
        self.assertIsInstance(d1, dict, 'First argument is not a dictionary')
        self.assertIsInstance(d2, dict, 'Second argument is not a dictionary')
        if d1 != d2:
            standardMsg = '%s != %s' % _common_shorten_repr(d1, d2)
            diff = ('\n' + '\n'.join(difflib.ndiff(
                           pprint.pformat(d1).splitlines(),
                           pprint.pformat(d2).splitlines())))
            standardMsg = standardMsg + diff
            raise AssertionError('%s : %s' % (standardMsg, msg))

    def assertIsInstance(self, obj, cls, msg=None):
        if not isinstance(obj, cls):
            standardMsg = '%s is not an instance of %r' % (safe_repr(obj), cls)
            raise AssertionError('%s : %s' % (standardMsg, msg))


__ASSERTER = Asserter()  # only one required
assertEqual = __ASSERTER.assertEqual  # get a reference to the method


def main():
    assertEqual({'a': 1, 'b': 2},
                {'a': 1, 'b': 456789})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which produces :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stack_overflow/so70675609.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/stack_overflow/so70675609.py", line 51, in main
    assertEqual({'a': 1, 'b': 2},
  File "/home/stack_overflow/so70675609.py", line 11, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "/home/stack_overflow/so70675609.py", line 38, in assertDictEqual
    raise AssertionError('%s : %s' % (standardMsg, msg))
AssertionError: {'a': 1, 'b': 2} != {'a': 1, 'b': 456789}
- {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
?               ^

+ {'a': 1, 'b': 456789}
?               ^^^^^^
 : None
```